# how to get all image base64 string from sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have base64 string in my sqlite database and I am sending all these record to server. I am facing problem that when I am trying to send these base64 string to server it sends only first raw record and then it sends null for other rows. I debug my code and I see that first time it chek my if condition but for second row it chek else condition. how can I solve that ?

```
class async_SaveImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespacegetlistdata, method_name__image);

            cursorImage = db.rawQuery("select * from FieldTestDataFinal Where isSend ='N'", null);
            /*for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
            {*/
            int k = 0;
            try {
                if (cursorImage.moveToFirst()) {

/*while (cursor.moveToNext())*/
                    do {
                        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                        //request.properties.clear();
                        if (k == 0) {
                            request.addProperty("fileByte1", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE1")));//add the parameters
                            request.addProperty("fileName1", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName1")));//add the parameters

                            request.addProperty("fileByte2", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE2")));//add the parameters
                            request.addProperty("fileName2", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName2")));//add the parameters

                            request.addProperty("fileByte3", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE3")));//add the parameters
                            request.addProperty("fileName3", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName3")));//add the parameters

                            request.addProperty("fileByte4", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE4")));//add the parameters
                            request.addProperty("fileName4", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName4")));//add the parameters

                            request.addProperty("fileByte5", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE5")));//add the parameters
                            request.addProperty("fileName5", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName5")));//add the parameters

                            request.addProperty("fileByte6", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("SIGNATURE_CONSUMER")));//add the parameters
                            request.addProperty("fileName6", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName6")));//add the parameters
                            // request.addProperty("fileName", "123.jpeg");//add the parametershe parameters
                        } else {
                            request.setProperty(0, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE1")));//add the parameters
                            request.setProperty(1, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName1")));//add the parameters

                            request.setProperty(0, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE2")));//add the parameters
                            request.setProperty(1, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName2")));//add the parameters

                            request.setProperty(0, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE3")));//add the parameters
                            request.setProperty(1, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName3")));//add the parameters

                            request.setProperty(0, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE4")));//add the parameters
                            request.setProperty(1, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName4")));//add the parameters

                            request.setProperty(0, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE5")));//add the parameters
                            request.setProperty(1, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName5")));//add the parameters

                            request.setProperty(0, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("SIGNATURE_CONSUMER")));//add the parameters
                            request.setProperty(1, cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName6")));//add the parameters
                        }
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//set soap version
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        try {
                            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url_getlistdata);
                            androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action_uploadImage, envelope);  // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                            //SoapPrimitive prim = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                            //hideDialog();


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d("myError -", String.valueOf(e));
                        }
                        k++;
                    } while (cursorImage.moveToNext());

                       /* object = new JSONObject();
                        object.put("data", arr);*/
                }
                cursorImage.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            // }

            return resultSaveAllData;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {
            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            super.onPostExecute(result1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ya I am replacing property in else condition but for first time it check if condition but for second time why it check else ? i am doing something wrong in if else thats why it checks else.

Comment: So what shouls I have to change ?

Comment: My requirement is assume I have three records in my sqlite but its only sending first record to server. Why its not sending all records ?

Comment: In a single request?

Comment: No not in single request. I want to call my api 3 times if I have three records.

Comment: Request property is doin insert and set property is for update.

Comment: Why do you have the `if(k == 0){} else {}` ?

Comment: Actually what happening if I remove if(k ==0) condition from code then its binding all rows one after another and every time its saves only first row. I want to clear request every time when its getting data from sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    cursorImage = db.rawQuery("select * from FieldTestDataFinal Where isSend ='N'", null);
    for (cursorImage.moveToFirst(); !cursorImage.isAfterLast(); cursorImage.moveToNext()) {
        result.append(sendRequest(cursorImage));
    }

    return result.toString();
}

private String sendRequest(Cursor cursorImage){
    String responseDump = "";
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//set soap version
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespacegetlistdata, method_name__image);

    request.addProperty("fileByte1", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE1")));//add the parameters
    request.addProperty("fileName1", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName1")));//add the parameters

    request.addProperty("fileByte2", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE2")));//add the parameters
    request.addProperty("fileName2", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName2")));//add the parameters

    request.addProperty("fileByte3", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE3")));//add the parameters
    request.addProperty("fileName3", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName3")));//add the parameters

    request.addProperty("fileByte4", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE4")));//add the parameters
    request.addProperty("fileName4", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName4")));//add the parameters

    request.addProperty("fileByte5", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("METER_IMAGE5")));//add the parameters
    request.addProperty("fileName5", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName5")));//add the parameters

    request.addProperty("fileByte6", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("SIGNATURE_CONSUMER")));//add the parameters
    request.addProperty("fileName6", cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex("fileName6")));//add the parameters

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url_getlistdata);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;    
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action_uploadImage, envelope);
        responseDump = transport.responseDump;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("myError -", String.valueOf(e));
    }
    return responseDump;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Neeraj for Reply but unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: What is the issue?